# Can I add a caption to a datatable/html table between thead and tbody?

Tags: html, dom, datatables, caption

I want to display text below  and above  giving user instructions.
I'm using jquery dataTables to populate it but table follows HTML in front end.
Any suggestions? 
Here is a JFiddle:
    http://jsfiddle.net/PrateekParekh/fr2zztL0/6/

```
$('#source').dataTable({
    "aaData": src,
    "sPaginationType": "full_numbers",
    "bFilter": true,
    "bProcessing": true,
    "bRedraw": true,
    "bDestroy": true,
    "bInfo": false,
    "bLengthChange": false,

    "aoColumns": [
    {"mData": "Module Title"},
    {"mData": "Module ID"},
    {"mData": "Module Language"}
    ]      

    });
```

Comment: Can you share some code? something in jsfiddle or codepen would be great. thanks!

Comment: Added the jsfiddle link.Is there a way to insert text "Press Ctrl+Click To select" between the thead and tbody like a caption? Just that it needs to be between them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [fnDrawCallback](http://legacy.datatables.net/usage/callbacks#fnDrawCallback) for this. When the table is refreshed, all the data is cleared out so you lose any content added manually. The `fnDrawCallback` event is fired after each table redraw so we can use it to prepend your message.

```
'fnDrawCallback': function(oSettings) {
    $("<tr colspan='2'><td>Press Ctrl+Click To select</td></tr>").prependTo("table > tbody");
}
```

See [here](https://jsfiddle.net/markps/2erL56tj/) for an updated version of your jsfiddle

Comment: Actually it's working as follows:                                       `'fnDrawCallback': function(oSettings) {
    $("<tr><td  colspan='2'>Press Ctrl+Click To select</td></tr>").prependTo("table > tbody");
}`                                                                                                                 The colspan needs to be in the td to have any effect.                                    Thank you for this idea.

Answer (score 1):

You could use this code!

`$('#source').append('<caption style="caption-side: top">...</caption>');
$('#source').dataTable({
...
})`

This adds a caption to the datatable on the position you chose in the 
`"caption-side: top/bottom/left/right`